# Agrandar gráficos en ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

tengo el siguiente problema: tengo un data frame con 149 países y diversas medidas de cada uno de ellos. Quiero  hacer el siguiente gráfico en ggplot 2:

`mi_grafico= ggplot(whr2021, aes(x = Social.support, y = Perceptions.of.corruption, color = Country.name)) +  geom_point() +  labs(title = "World Happiness Report 21'. Social support vs. Perceptions of corruption",  x = "Social Suport",  y = "Perceptions of corruption") +  theme_minimal()`

pero cuando lo ejecuto me queda el gráfico muy pequeño y la lista de países ocupa casi toda la ventana.

[image: grafico en R]

Alguien sabe como puedo hacer para agrandar el gráfico y disminuir el nombre de los países.
Gracias!!

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Pues es mucha la información a mostrar, no es mucho lo que se puede hacer, tal vez es el momento de replantear el gráfico ¿Es necesario identificar cada uno de los países? ¿Se podría plantear lo mismo pero facetado por continente? ¿Qué es lo que quieres contar? En cuanto al problema en sí, podría sugerirte dos caminos

```
ggplot(whr2021, aes(x = Social.support, y = Perceptions.of.corruption, color = Country.name)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "World Happiness Report 21'.\nSocial support vs. Perceptions of corruption",  
       x = "Social Suport",  y = "Perceptions of corruption") +  
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=14)) +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=8))
```

Aquí simplemente:

- Ponemos la leyenda debajo del gráfico `theme(legend.position="bottom")`
- Quitamos el titulo "Country name" con `theme(legend.title=element_blank())` para ganar un poco más de espacio
- Con `guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=14))` indicamos 14 columnas para la leyenda
- Por último con `theme(legend.text=element_text(size=8))` achicamos un poca la letra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La otra alternativa, es no usar leyendas por etiquetas con los nombres del país directamente en el gráfico, esto se puede hacer con `ggplot` estándar pero es mucho mejor el resultado usando el paquete `ggrepel`:

```
ggplot(whr2021, aes(x = Social.support, y = Perceptions.of.corruption, color = Country.name)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "World Happiness Report 21'.\nSocial support vs. Perceptions of corruption",  
       x = "Social Suport",  y = "Perceptions of corruption") +  
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=Country.name), size=3) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

Estamos usando `geom_text_repel()` este `geom` intenta acomodar las etiquetas para que cada texto no se superpongan con otra (Puede ocurrir que algunas etiquetas no se muestren por que se superponen con otras).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: es fundamental que visualices o exportes el gráfico con el mayor tamaño posible.

Comment: Perfecto! muchas gracias Patricio!!